# intellij golang plugin debug always compiles

Tags: go, intellij-idea, goland

i am using `181.4668.90` version of the Go plugin in Intellij and everything looks great. When debugging a golang test case, it necessarily does a `compiling` step, which is somewhat understandable. However, even when there is no changes to the golang source code, in the subsequent debug invocation, there is again the `compiling` step, which takes up a pretty significant amount of time.

Are there any workarounds that can be employed? I don't see any exceptions or the kind on the ide logs.

In general, does Intellij look for the compiled sources to be available on `GOPATH` before starting the debugger?
 Thanks!

`IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.3 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-181.4892.42, built on May 7, 2018
macOS 10.13.5
go version go1.9.6 darwin/amd64`

Answer (score 2):

Regardless if you use IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate or GoLand, the IDE won't compile the source code itself, it will defer that to the Go compiler.

If you want to speed up the compilation step, upgrade to the latest Go available, Go 1.11.2 at the time of writing, as the Go compiler suffered massive improvements to build caching in Go 1.10. As you haven't specified which Go version you are running, I'm going to assume it's 1.9 or earlier.

Comment: Thanks! will try out with the new version.